# Conditional Probability Problem with Patrons at a Convention

Tags: probability

> At the entrance to a motor vehicle  convention ($\textit{CarCon}$), patrons were asked
>   to indicate whether they were fans of vehcicle $A, B$ and $C$. $60\%$ of patrons were vehicle $A$ fans, and $30\%$ were vehcile $C$ fans. The probability that a vehicle $A$ fan was also a fan of vehicle $B$ was $0.3$, and that they were also a vehicle $C$ fan was $0.40$.

From the passage we know that $Pr(A) = 0.60$ and $Pr(C) = 0.30$. We also know that $Pr(B|A) = 0.30$ and $Pr(C|A) = 0.40$.

(a) What is the probability that a patron at $\textit{CarCon}$ was a fan of both $A$ and $B$?

$$Pr(AB) = Pr(B|A) \times Pr(A)= 0.30 \times 0.60 = 0.18$$

(b) If $70\%$ of patrons who were not vehicle $A$ fans were fans of vehicle $B$, what is the probability that a patron at  $\textit{CarCon}$ was a fan of vehicle $B$?

From the question we have,

$$Pr(B|\overline{A}) = 0.70$$

We also know that,

$$Pr(B|\overline{A})\times Pr(\overline{A}) = Pr(B\overline{A})$$
$$0.70\times 0.40 = 0.28$$

From basically probability rules it follows,

$$Pr(B) = Pr(BA) + Pr(B\overline{A})$$
$$Pr(B) = 0.18 + 0.28 = 0.46$$

Is this solution correct? I feel as though it isn't.

Comment: Looks good to me. What part makes you feel uneasy?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly state that they could only choose one, but the question states "patrons were asked to indicate whether they were fans of vehicle A,, B and C". Since 60% of patrons were vehicle A fans, and 30% were vehicle C fans, I have this inclining that it should be 10% of patrons identified as liking B. But then again, I guess they weren't restricted to one selection.

Comment: Your answer is correct. As per your concern in the comment, it is negated by the question itself where it states "The probability that a vehicle A fan was also a fan of vehicle B was 0.3". The two events are not disjoint.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for the clarification @Shinja @mlc!